# google calendar in today view in ipad (iOS 14) is displaying "unable to load"

Tags: ipad, google-calendar, ios

Since the upgrade to iOS 14 my work iPad has been showing "unable to load", in the google calendar widget in today view.

Has this widget been broken in iOS 14?, or is it miss-configured. I have searched the setting, but can not get it to work.

How can I get a calendar of upcoming events on my home screen, and lock window?

Comment: Did Google offer an upgrade of the app for iOS 14?  If not, you have to wait until they put one out.

Comment: @fsb did apple break comparability?

Comment: It's Apple's API so they could've deprecated the code or made changes, companies do that quite often, and developers have to make changes.  When a major OS is released, old code is removed.  There's several apps that I use that had this problem early in beta cycle and they had to quickly Testflight their fixes.

Comment: @fsb I have not had this problem with Android, Gnu/Linux, or ever MS-Windows. But if this is the apple way, then it is what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just updated to 14.2 and it magically started working again.